# adding a score counter to an already existing game javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to expand on an already existing JavaScript project i coded along with by adding a score counter to a simple game where you control a GIF image with arrow keys, and collect a coin which randomly appears on the page. My attempts so far have been unsuccessful.

**HTML code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Coin Game Starter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id= "scoreboard">0</h1>
  <img id="player" src="https://media.tenor.com/images/0791eb3858075aca85eed5ecfe08c778/tenor.gif" alt="">
  <img id="coin" src="coin.gif" alt="">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS code:**

```js
function isTouching(a, b) {
 const aRect = a.getBoundingClientRect();
 const bRect = b.getBoundingClientRect();

 return !(
  aRect.top + aRect.height < bRect.top ||
  aRect.top > bRect.top + bRect.height ||
  aRect.left + aRect.width < bRect.left ||
  aRect.left > bRect.left + bRect.width
 );
}


const avatar = document.querySelector('#player')
const coin = document.querySelector('#coin')

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
 if(e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
 const currTop = extractPos (avatar.style.top)
 avatar.style.top = `${currTop + 50}px`
 
} 
 else if (e.key === 'ArrowUp'){
 const currTop = extractPos (avatar.style.top)
 avatar.style.top = `${currTop - 50}px`
 
}
else if (e.key === 'ArrowRight'){
 const currLeft = extractPos (avatar.style.left)
 avatar.style.left = `${currLeft + 50}px`
 avatar.style.transform = 'scale(1,1)'
 
}
else if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft'){
 const currLeft = extractPos (avatar.style.left)
 avatar.style.left = `${currLeft - 50}px`
 avatar.style.transform = 'scale(-1,1)'
 
}

if(isTouching(avatar, coin)) moveCoin ()
});


const moveCoin = () => {
 const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
 const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight);
 coin.style.top = `${y}px`;
 coin.style.left = `${x}px`;
}


const extractPos = (pos) => {
 if(!pos) return 0
 return parseInt(pos.slice(0,-2))
}

const score = document.getElementById('scoreboard')
 
const coinScore = score
function scoreUp () {
 
 if (isTouching){
  score ++
 }
 score.textContent = score
}
```

the bottom of the js page shows where i have tried to write a function that causes the score to increase upon the player grabbing the coin

Comment: Where do you call the scoreUp function? Maybe call it if isTouching is true.

Answer (score 0):

you made the score variable a constant. change it to look like this and see if it works

```js
let score = document.getElementById('scoreboard') 
let coinScore = score

function scoreUp () {

 if (isTouching){
  score ++
 }
 score.textContent = score
}
```